# Can't send e-mail through Java

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email through my Java application. Every time I try to send I get the following error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 <email>: sender address must contain a domain;
```

Nested exception is:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 <email>: sender address must contain a domain;
```

My sender is a work email:

```
String from = "system@midrandchildwelfare.org.za";
```

My host is:

```
String host = "mail.midrandchildwelfare.org.za";
```

Sending through port `587`.

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Some servers do not append the domain name so that it fail and the exception is just like yours
you need to make your email like
"email@company.com"

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [api documentation](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html!):

```
Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
tr.connect(smtphost, username, password);
msg.saveChanges();      // don't forget this
tr.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
tr.close();
```

Are you sure you have the smtp server address correct?